# Como soluciono este error: npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE?

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero instalar Reactjs pero al momento de hacerlo me encuentro con estos errores.

Answer (score 1):

esto usualmente sucede porque hay algún problema con la validación de los certificados ssl de la librería que intentas utilizar, esto tambien sucede por algunas configuraciones especificas del proxy.
Una solucion que te puede servir es desactivar la validacion ssl, para que "confíe" en cualquier origen e instale las librerias.
El comando para hacer eso es el siguiente:

> `npm config set strict-ssl false`

Y posteriormente para evitar algun conflicto de caché puedes limpiar el caché de npm con:

> `npm cache clean --force`